# How can I debug memory leaks in react-native Expo project?

Tags: react-native, memory-leaks, profiling, genymotion, expo

I am running a react-native Expo project on both ios simulator, which uses XCode, and android emulator, which uses genymotion.
There is a crash sometimes when using the app on real android phone.
I am hoping to find out the reason debugging it on the emulator.

So far, I searched for tools for this, but did not encounter any.

Could anyone tell me available tools for debugging memory leaks on genymotion emulator?
I also welcome any other advices to fix my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can gain a ton of insight using [Infinite Red's Reactitron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron)

You might also want to check out `Perf Monitor` which you can access from the Debug menu.

There's a whole page on profiling and troubleshooting perf issues in the react native documentation.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging

Answer (score 0):

With Expo you'll need to detach.

For Android you can find tutorial [here](https://shift.infinite.red/react-native-android-app-memory-investigation-55695625da9c).

For iOS:

1. Make sure you have Release Schema
2. Go to XCode → Product → Profile (⌘ + i) and you'll find:
   [image]
3. It should open your leaks profiler on the screen and then click on the red dot.
   [image]
4. Restart the app in simulator.
5. You should see your memory allocations in the leaks profiler window.

Comment: Trying this, the simulator opens, shows the React Native launch screen, (which includes my project name and the "Powered by React Native", but then never loads my app. All I get are a bunch of green checkmarks in the Leaks row. Is there something else I need to be doing to get my app to run under Leaks mode?