# Android WebView memory leak with videos

Tags: android, html, memory, video, webview

We got a webapp loaded using WebView on an Android app, that is playing a sequence of videos in a loop, one after the other.

After a couple of hours or sometimes days, eventually the Android app is killed by the OS, for running out of memory. Memory size growth is not necessarily consistent and has many times been step-wise.

It seems like the webapp is running just fine on a PC, loaded on a Chrome webbrowser, with a stable memory consumption.

I've read through whatever I could find on anything related to this issue, including issue discussions on Chrome development referring to issues with video playing and memory leaks, thinking maybe it has to do with the version of WebView, but I'm at a complete loss.

**Edit #1 - LeakCanary heap dump**

App process at around ~450 MB memory usage:

```
====================================
HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
====================================
2 APPLICATION LEAKS

References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.

103406 bytes retained by leaking objects
Displaying only 1 leak trace out of 2 with the same signature
Signature: 5171a6a892a950ce3f8a8c0f77b7886bc8840588
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker class
│    Leaking: NO (DevMenuActivity? is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
│    ? static StrictMode$InstanceTracker.sInstanceCounts
├─ java.util.HashMap instance
│    Leaking: NO (DevMenuActivity? is not leaking)
│    ? HashMap[key()]
├─ expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuActivity class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ? static DevMenuActivity.rootView
│                             ~~~~~~~~
├─ com.facebook.react.ReactRootView instance
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    Retaining 51.7 kB in 868 objects
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mID = R.id.null
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 2
│    mContext instance of expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    ? View.mContext
?? expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuActivity instance
?     Leaking: YES (Activity#mDestroyed is true)
?     Retaining 47.2 kB in 772 objects
?     mApplication instance of com.demo.app.MainApplication
?     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper

8400 bytes retained by leaking objects
Signature: 5b3899ea22e2a6db10174642f4e93bfa7276e8d4
┬───
│ GC Root: Thread object
│
├─ android.os.HandlerThread instance
│    Leaking: NO (PathClassLoader? is not leaking)
│    Thread name: 'plumber-android-leaks'
│    ? Thread.contextClassLoader
├─ dalvik.system.PathClassLoader instance
│    Leaking: NO (ReactCxxErrorHandler? is not leaking and A ClassLoader is never leaking)
│    ? ClassLoader.runtimeInternalObjects
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: NO (ReactCxxErrorHandler? is not leaking)
│    ? Object[5491]
├─ com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactCxxErrorHandler class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ? static ReactCxxErrorHandler.mObject
│                                  ~~~~~~~
├─ com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 789 B in 29 objects
│    mApplicationContext instance of com.demo.app.MainApplication
│    mCurrentActivity instance of expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    mCurrentReactContext instance of com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext, wrapping com.demo.app.MainApplication
│    ? ReactInstanceManager.mCurrentActivity
│                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
?? expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuActivity instance
?     Leaking: YES (Activity#mDestroyed is true)
?     Retaining 8.4 kB in 280 objects
?     mApplication instance of com.demo.app.MainApplication
?     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
====================================
0 LIBRARY LEAKS

A Library Leak is a leak caused by a known bug in 3rd party code that you do not have control over.
See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/#4-categorizing-leaks
====================================
0 UNREACHABLE OBJECTS

An unreachable object is still in memory but LeakCanary could not find a strong reference path
from GC roots.
====================================
METADATA

Please include this in bug reports and Stack Overflow questions.

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 28
Build.MANUFACTURER: Droidlogic
LeakCanary version: 2.13
App process name: com.demo.app
Class count: 19796
Instance count: 377276
Primitive array count: 151701
Object array count: 39257
Thread count: 74
Heap total bytes: 24599693
Bitmap count: 25
Bitmap total bytes: 15063704
Large bitmap count: 1
Large bitmap total bytes: 14267840
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=70232,misses=159685,hitRate=30%] RandomAccess[bytes=7537765,reads=159685,travel=46060288462,range=34066723,size=39464184]
Analysis duration: 5128 ms
Heap dump file path: D:\shark-cli\bin\2024-01-28_14-23-52_056-com.demo.app.hprof
Heap dump timestamp: 1706444663621
Heap dump duration: Unknown
====================================
```

App process at around ~550 MB memory usage:

```
====================================
HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
====================================
2 APPLICATION LEAKS

References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.

103406 bytes retained by leaking objects
Displaying only 1 leak trace out of 2 with the same signature
Signature: 5171a6a892a950ce3f8a8c0f77b7886bc8840588
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker class
│    Leaking: NO (DevMenuActivity? is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
│    ? static StrictMode$InstanceTracker.sInstanceCounts
├─ java.util.HashMap instance
│    Leaking: NO (DevMenuActivity? is not leaking)
│    ? HashMap[key()]
├─ expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuActivity class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ? static DevMenuActivity.rootView
│                             ~~~~~~~~
├─ com.facebook.react.ReactRootView instance
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    Retaining 51.7 kB in 868 objects
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mID = R.id.null
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 2
│    mContext instance of expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    ? View.mContext
?? expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuActivity instance
?     Leaking: YES (Activity#mDestroyed is true)
?     Retaining 47.2 kB in 772 objects
?     mApplication instance of com.demo.app.MainApplication
?     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper

8400 bytes retained by leaking objects
Signature: 5b3899ea22e2a6db10174642f4e93bfa7276e8d4
┬───
│ GC Root: Thread object
│
├─ android.os.HandlerThread instance
│    Leaking: NO (PathClassLoader? is not leaking)
│    Thread name: 'plumber-android-leaks'
│    ? Thread.contextClassLoader
├─ dalvik.system.PathClassLoader instance
│    Leaking: NO (ReactCxxErrorHandler? is not leaking and A ClassLoader is never leaking)
│    ? ClassLoader.runtimeInternalObjects
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: NO (ReactCxxErrorHandler? is not leaking)
│    ? Object[5491]
├─ com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactCxxErrorHandler class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ? static ReactCxxErrorHandler.mObject
│                                  ~~~~~~~
├─ com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 789 B in 29 objects
│    mApplicationContext instance of com.demo.app.MainApplication
│    mCurrentActivity instance of expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    mCurrentReactContext instance of com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext, wrapping com.demo.app.MainApplication
│    ? ReactInstanceManager.mCurrentActivity
│                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
?? expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuActivity instance
?     Leaking: YES (Activity#mDestroyed is true)
?     Retaining 8.4 kB in 280 objects
?     mApplication instance of com.demo.app.MainApplication
?     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
====================================
0 LIBRARY LEAKS

A Library Leak is a leak caused by a known bug in 3rd party code that you do not have control over.
See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/#4-categorizing-leaks
====================================
0 UNREACHABLE OBJECTS

An unreachable object is still in memory but LeakCanary could not find a strong reference path
from GC roots.
====================================
METADATA

Please include this in bug reports and Stack Overflow questions.

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 28
Build.MANUFACTURER: Droidlogic
LeakCanary version: 2.13
App process name: com.demo.app
Class count: 19804
Instance count: 393062
Primitive array count: 153287
Object array count: 39892
Thread count: 76
Heap total bytes: 25136426
Bitmap count: 27
Bitmap total bytes: 15083768
Large bitmap count: 1
Large bitmap total bytes: 14267840
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=71017,misses=162839,hitRate=30%] RandomAccess[bytes=7681412,reads=162839,travel=47068700886,range=34908331,size=40312864]
Analysis duration: 5124 ms
Heap dump file path: D:\shark-cli\bin\2024-01-28_15-30-33_624-com.demo.app.hprof
Heap dump timestamp: 1706448672183
Heap dump duration: Unknown
====================================
```

It seems like one of the reported leaks are related to the development build; the dev tools added by Expo, which are not implemented in production build.

**Edit #2 - App logcat crash report**

https://pastebin.com/j8EEdRwm

**Edit #3 - Revised LeakCanary heap dump**

It seems like the previous leaks were false-positives, caused by the Expo development build tools that I had installed when I was setting up LeakCanary, thinking they were necessary; turns out they were not. LeakCanary shows no leaks.

```
====================================
HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
====================================
0 APPLICATION LEAKS

References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
====================================
0 LIBRARY LEAKS

A Library Leak is a leak caused by a known bug in 3rd party code that you do not have control over.
See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/#4-categorizing-leaks
====================================
0 UNREACHABLE OBJECTS

An unreachable object is still in memory but LeakCanary could not find a strong reference path
from GC roots.
====================================
METADATA

Please include this in bug reports and Stack Overflow questions.

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 28
Build.MANUFACTURER: Droidlogic
LeakCanary version: 2.13
App process name: com.demo.app
Class count: 16718
Instance count: 178810
Primitive array count: 126144
Object array count: 20493
Thread count: 60
Heap total bytes: 16518291
Bitmap count: 4
Bitmap total bytes: 14288960
Large bitmap count: 1
Large bitmap total bytes: 14267840
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=43998,misses=100025,hitRate=30%] RandomAccess[bytes=4654876,reads=100025,travel=28222246297,range=21884124,size=26729841]
Analysis duration: 3303 ms
Heap dump file path: D:\shark-cli\bin\2024-01-28_17-41-34_818-com.demo.app.hprof
Heap dump timestamp: 1706456519327
Heap dump duration: Unknown
====================================
```

Comment: Might be hard to work on that without any leak traces (like from LeakCanary) or the code itself

Comment: Try adding [LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/) into your project and try to make it leak (we will get a trace that should give us a hint)

Comment: @JustSightseeing thank you. The last couple of hours I have been working on getting LeakCanary hooked up to the app. The app is built on Expo React Native. I downloaded Flipper, got it to detect my physical Android device and the app's development build. On the latest Flipper Windows build (0.239.0), React DevTools and LeakCanary plugins show as unavailable. On older builds (e.g. 0.223.0), React DevTools is available (and works perfectly), yet LeakCanary still shows as unavailable. Am I missing something? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Wasn't aware the project is in React native, then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444793/how-can-i-debug-memory-leaks-in-react-native-expo-project)? (I have no experience with react, so it's just a random guess)

Comment: @JustSightseeing thank you. After digging through your link, and many hours of jumping around multiple resources without success, I managed to add the LeakCanary debug dependency to the native Java code compiled from the Expo React Native code. I can now see LeakCanary running on my notifications bar of my physical device and detecting leaks. Part of my problem is not knowing how to consistently reproduce the leak, relying only on leaving the app long enough. I will make another update as soon as I have one.

Comment: You do not need to reproduce it `consistently` (unless there's multiple things leaking, but that's rare), you need it to leak only once, then paste the log here and we can get some details about the problem :)

Comment: @JustSightseeing I have edited the question with updated data. My reproduction of the memory leak as of yet relies entirely on time, I don't know how to do it on demand. I'm not sure if I'm reading the report properly, but I'm not certain we are seeing any helpful memory leak here.

Comment: @JustSightseeing fyi, the app seems to have been killed by the OS. I have captured the logcat report, but it's too large to be posted here. Even though I'm still figuring out how to read it, I do see multiple references to WebView in there.

Comment: you can post it on PasteBin (but make sure it won't disappear, for future devs)

Answer (score 0):

The leak canary seems to have identified 2 of the possible leak sources:

1. `expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuActivity` class (this leak seems to be the ReactRootView instance. View.mContext seems to be referencing a destroyed activity. The ReactRootView instance is retaining 51.7 kB in 868 objects. The DevMenuActivity instance itself is also marked as leaking and retaining 47.2 kB in 772 objects)
2. `com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager` (However, the status of this leak is unknown. The ReactInstanceManager instance is retaining 789 B in 29 objects. The DevMenuActivity instance is again involved in this leak, and it's marked as leaking with 8.4 kB in 280 objects)

I've managed to find [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37105) that seems to match the second problem, but it may be worth to look into the DevMenuActivity itself (hard to work without the code in this case)

Comment: Please have a look at "Edit #3" that I just added to the main post. Is there anything else to do on the app memory, or does the update indicate that we're looking at issues within the JS memory inside the WebView?